# how to reduce the processing time of this certain block of code?

Tags: matlab, optimization

i've made an algorithm in which i've to perform this thing almost around 100 times. i want to reduce the processing time of this block of code, can someone help me in reducing its processing time or suggest me an efficient block of code instead of this? in my laptop, this block is takin around "Elapsed time is 29.213608 seconds." when it is executed once. if i multiply this elapsed time by 100, then the answer come out to be around 48.7 minutes which is a big processing time. if someone can plz help me in this thing, i'll be grateful ;)
actually i want to invert the bits of a, and a is of type char, and i was not able to invert the bits by applying not operation. then i learnt it somewhere that not operation in matlab is not applicable on type char, so i first converted the bits from char to double, then applied not operation, and then converted the resultant matrix back into type char from double. my main purpose is to invert the bits which are of type char. if someone can do it in another way, so plz help me. this thing is taking alot of processing time :(

```
tic;
a(1:1000000,1)='0';

c=str2num(a);

c=~c;

d=num2str(c);

toc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
b = repmat('0',size(a));
b(a=='0') = '1';
```

Or:

```
ind = a=='0';
a(ind) = '1';
a(~ind) = '0';
```

Comment: @LuisMendo the above code u suggested is the fastest :)
and yup, Divakar, ur both codes are working too :)
but if u compare ur both codes elapsed time, then this is taking less time compared to other one, but when i checked the processing time of this code with the processing time of Luis Mendo code, then Luis Mendo code was working more fast.. but thanks to both of u :)
ind = a=='0';
a(ind) = '1';
a(~ind) = '0';

Comment: Divakar the time for ur code is: Elapsed time is 0.273470 seconds.
while @LuisMendo Mendo, the time for ur code is: Elapsed time is 0.190165 seconds.
but thanks to both of u for helping me so much :)
that's so nice of u both :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this -

```
num2str((a-'0')==0)
```

Or using ascii equivalents -

```
char((a==48)+48) %// Thanks to Luis!
```

Or this -

```
char(97-a)
```

Comment: +1 I suggest `char(((a-'0')==0)+'0')`. More symmetric and you get rid of spaces

Comment: Or maybe `char((a=='0')+'0')` will be faster

Comment: @LuisMendo Okay, I stole that! :)

Comment: ...and improved it! That has to be the fastest

Comment: @LuisMendo Nothing like raw data! ;)

Comment: thanks luis and @Divakar for giving me the suggestions and helping me :)
and yup, Luis this is the fatest among the given answers :)
char((a=='0'))+'0');

Comment: @Divakar i checked all the suggested codes and tested all of them, now my final conclusion is that luis codes are fast when we've small no.of values in a matrix, ur codes are faster when we've large no.of values in a matrix. thanks again both of u :)